# Azure Postgres Flexible Server Vnet

Tags: postgresql, azure, vnet

I have azure flexible postgres instance with vnet integration.
It work fine with my webapp integration.
However, i would to have a on-premise external connection to this pg instance.
Is there a way to do that with flexible postgres vnet ?

Thanks

Comment: I think , i can use vpn gateway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal

Comment: Hi @Mascence if you solved your issue kindly post as an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem

Comment: Ha yes . sorry !

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working with vpn gateway.
I was able to connect my remote server to the virtual network through this way
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal

Comment: it's written in the docs :) "Use VPN or Azure ExpressRoute to connect from non-Azure resources to your flexible server." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking